# Javascript indexOf method not working with integers in Object

Tags: javascript

I have made a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/csS24/

I'm trying to get the code to a point, that it never ever shows the same two items at once or when one item is clicked, it never pulls back that same one from the array, just seem to be struggling a little with the logic and the indexOf method is behaving oddly.

```
var justAdded = [];
justAdded['first'] = 0;
justAdded['second'] = 1;

newHtml = returnRandom().split('|');

justAdded[e.id] = parseInt(newHtml[0], 10);

    if(justAdded.indexOf(parseInt(newHtml[0], 10)) == -1){
        e.style.opacity = 0;
        e.innerHTML = newHtml[1];
        e.style.opacity = 1;
        e.setAttribute('data-id', newHtml[0]);
    } else {
        uniq(clickedEl);
    }

var returnRandom = function(){
    return options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)]
};
```

e.id will be equal to 'first' or 'second'. returnRandom() will grab a random value from the options array:

```
var options = [
    '0|Flash',
    '1|Internet Explorer',
    '2|Java',
    '3|!important'
];
```

Comment: How about posting your code here. I'd think you'd know to do that after asking over 400 and answering over 200 questions.

Comment: @amnotiam its all pretty relevant but here are the main points

Comment: JS built-in function don't behave oddly - only user functions (and PHP library functions) do that.

Comment: You're using an array as an object. O_o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be adding *non-numeric properties* to an Array.

The `indexOf()` method is intended to work on and return numeric properties.

Furthermore...

- the `processAnswer` handler passes the ID of the element to `addHtml`... like "first", "second"
- `addHtml` uses that ID string to grab the very same element stored in a variable with the same name, and then passes that element to `uniq`
- `uniq` adds a property to the `justAdded` Array, with the key being the ID of the element.

You keep switching between passing elements and their IDs, and using the one to get the other in every next function. All that is to say that your code seems terribly disorganized, and I think you just need to start from scratch and rethink your code.

---

Also, what the heck is with this?...

```
var options = [
    '0|Flash',
    '1|Internet Explorer',
    '2|Java',
    '3|!important'
];
```

Why are you hardcoding indices into strings in the Array? Arrays are ordered lists. They already have the indices taken care of.

```
var options = [
    'Flash',                // 0
    'Internet Explorer',    // 1
    'Java',                 // 2
    '!important'            // 3
];
```